# What are the building blocks of Virtual Dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, virtual-dom

I have a rough understanding of what virtual dom is, but I don't understand how and what it takes to build a virtual dom "library". Here is what I know and understand so far:

- Virtual Nodes that are turned into real nodes
- Virtual Text that are turned into real text nodes
- Observe for changes (state of the element) in order to avoid re-rendering?

Here are some useful resources that I found:

- [Virtual Dom vs Dom](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/the-difference-between-virtual-dom-and-dom/)
- [What is Virtual Dom?](https://cardlife.blog/what-is-virtual-dom-c0ec6d6a925c)

Am I on the right track?

Thank you!

Comment: Wow downvote, I'm just asking for general information. I looked into existing libraries in order to roughly understand. I'm not trying to build one.

Comment: Welcome to the ever friendly SO community <3

Comment: @FreemanLambda loool haha

Comment: You most likely got a downvote because your question is verging on [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Try and frame your question as a specific problem you need help understanding.

Comment: @Damon I'm just trying to understand what it takes to build a virtual dom library (not that I'm going to build one), just want general knowledge. I get the concept behind Virtual Dom. I don't know how more specific I can get. Thanks for your input, not going against what you commented, explaining myself that's all.

Comment: It is like @Damon said. Your questions will not be welcome if they are very specif or very general. You are on the right track IMO. If you come across difficulties in your road that are more suitable for the SO question format, just go ahead and ask here. Do not get discouraged by these cowardly downvoters that do not even bother to explain their reasons in a comment.

Comment: @FreemanLambda okay will do, thanks a lot. I thought it  would be interesting to have some kind of discussion it but fine no problem, I guess it's more appropriate to ask it in a "Forum". Only thing that baffles me is that this is where I can get more exposure to developers and I can have great inputs from others. (It can benefit other people not only myself) Thanks again.